# Save all music files in a VLC xspf playlist to another folder

Tags: command-line, vlc, playlists

I have a VLC playlist (.xspf) of over a 100 songs all scattered all over my computer. I'm looking for a way to save this playlist and all it's songs to another folder - flash drive, external drive or just a different location in my computer. How can I do this?

**EDIT**

The xspf playlist is in XML and is such a format:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<playlist xmlns="http://xspf.org/ns/0/" xmlns:vlc="http://www.videolan.org/vlc/playlist/ns/0/" version="1">
    <title>Playlist</title>
    <trackList>
        <track>
            <location>file:///home/subroot/Music/3%20Days%20Grace%20-%20Wake%20Up.mp3</location>
            <title>Wake Up</title>
            <creator>3 Days Grace</creator>
            <album>Three Days Grace</album>
            <trackNum>10</trackNum>
            <annotation> </annotation>
            <duration>206036</duration>
            <extension application="http://www.videolan.org/vlc/playlist/0">
                <vlc:id>0</vlc:id>
            </extension>
        </track>
        .
        . [Many more tracks here]
        .
    </trackList>
    <extension application="http://www.videolan.org/vlc/playlist/0">
            <vlc:item tid="0"/>
            .
            . [Other id's here]
            .
    </extension>
</playlist>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it, assuming that none of your file names contain `<`:

```
grep -Po 'file://\K[^<]+' now.xspf | while IFS= read -r file; do
    song="${file//%20/ }"
    cp "$song" /path/to/target;
done
```

#### Explanation

The `-o` flag tells `grep` to only print the matched portion of a line and the `-P` activates Perl Compatible Regular Expressions which give us `\K`. The `\K` causes `grep` to discard everything matched before it so the result is that `file://\K[^<]+` will match the longest string of non-`<` characters that come after `file://`.

This is then fed to a while loop with `IFS=` to turn off word splitting at whitespace and `-r` to treat backslashes as normal characters.

The line `SONG="${file//%20/ }"` converts all `%20` to  (empty space). Otherwise, it returns a 'path not found' error when it tries to copy the songs in the last line.

If your file names can contain `<`, use this instead:

```
perl -lne '@foo=(m#file://(.+?)</location>#g); END{print $_ for @foo}' playlist.xspf |
while IFS= read -r file; do
    cp "$file" /path/to/target/;
done
```

**Note:** Both solutions assume that none of your file names contain newlines.

Comment: This may be useful if the path to your audio files is missing/broken in the XPSF: https://sourceforge.net/projects/xspf2m3u/